# Is there a way to add a subreport to the header of an RDLC report?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, rdlc

I am looking for a way to add a "subreport" (or something equivilent) to the header of a RDLC report in Visual Studio 2008.  I have a block of information that I would like to pass in via a parameter, but I only want to display it once.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found out a way to do it.  I just added a text box to the Page Header and a new parameter (which contains the information that I want to display).  Then I set the text box contents to the value of the parameter.